# grunt-usemin relative image links

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-usemin, yeoman-generator-angular, grunt-contrib-cssmin

I have very common issue, read a lot of solutions (both stackoverflow and github issues), but still haven't found that would work for me.

What I'm trying to solve:

1. **angularjs** project, so Im using *generator-angular* (yeoman generator)
2. **SASS** preprocessor (actually doesn' metter)
3. need to use **relative image links** (../../images/yeoman.png), so they are **correct before and after build** (../images/yeoman.1er4b3.png)

---

I created [**test project for that**](https://github.com/SpeedShifter/usemin-relative-images).
To test use:

```
grunt serve:build
```

Only the solution worked for me you can find in [**this commit**](https://github.com/SpeedShifter/usemin-relative-images/commit/460de2f6e379a41fab24d6faeaafa4c82b4a3fac)

```
cssmin: {
  options: {
    target: '.tmp/styles/any.css',
    relativeTo: '.tmp/styles/'
  }
}
```

But it has problem: 
if compiled (after build) css file locates in *dist/styles/subfolder/* (index.html contains < !-- build:css({.tmp,app}) styles/views/views.css -->), links will be broken.

---

This issue is connected with **grunt-cotrib-cssmin** -> **clean-css**.

***Note:*** generator-angular creates Gruntfile with latest solution I saw in helps, but it doesn't helps in my case

```
usemin: {
  html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
  css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/**/*.css'],
  options: {
    assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>','<%= yeoman.dist %>/images']
  }
},
```

Will be happy if somebody will make **[test project](https://github.com/SpeedShifter/usemin-relative-images)** build normally.

Comment: the solution in the very bottom helped me. adding '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images' to assertDirs